# Strange String prints out, how do I fix that? And com.packagename@<Some HexCode>

Tags: java, android, string, tostring, gettext

I want to print out the String newNewsString in a Background Service, but all I get when I print it is `rO0ABXNyABVzYXZlbG9hZC5GaWVsZEVsZW1lbnSkSqvd/QVXVAIABVoADWlzSW1wbGVtZW50ZWRM`...I got a com.packagename@SomeHexCode result earlier, but I somehow got that away, does someone also know how to fix that hex?
How can I get the normal result?

Here is the code I tried:

```
public void getAktuelles(SharedPreferences sharedPref) throws Exception {
    List<News> news = Utils.getNewsFromHTML(Utils.getHTML("http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/22-0-Aktuelle+Meldungen.html"));
    String newNewsString = new ObjectSaver().saveString(news);
    String oldNewsString = sharedPref.getString("aktuellesList", "");
    int UniqueID = getUniqueID();

    if(!oldNewsString.equals(newNewsString)) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPref.edit();
        edit.putString("aktuellesList", newNewsString);
        edit.commit();
        myString = newNewsString;

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.nclogo)
                        .setContentTitle("Gemeinde Aktuelle Meldungen")
                        .setContentText(sharedPref.getString("aktuellesList", null));
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, AktuellesActivity.class);
        android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(AktuellesActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(UniqueID, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(UniqueID, mBuilder.build());
        System.out.println(newNewsString + " " + oldNewsString + " 000Hallo" + " " + sharedPref.getString("aktuellesList", null));
    }
}
```

Maybe should I try getText() or toString(), does anyone have an idea how to get the "normal" result (Should be text of a newsheadline)

Comment: You should post the clear code remove all the unused code or commented code.

Comment: That looks like the base64 encoding of something, so either base64 decode it, or figure out how to get an unencoded version.

Comment: @blm Yeah, and that's what I want to know - How do I get the uncoded version?